# How to list files in S3 bucket using Spark Session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to list all of the files in given S3 path (ex: s3://my-bucket/my-folder/*.extension) using a SparkSession object?

Comment: What is the use case that you trying to achieve?

Comment: I know it is possible to do this using the AWS S3 SDK API but was wondering if it is supported in the SparkSession object. I am interested in counting how many files in a specific S3 path contain a particular file format (ex: *.extension) and also would like to know its' full path / file name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use Hadoop API for accessing files on S3 (Spark uses it as well):

```
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val path = "s3://somebucket/somefolder"
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), new Configuration())
val it = fileSystem.listFiles(new Path(path), true)
while (it.hasNext()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: this is the way to do it, and the listFiles(path, true) can give you much better performance with s3 than trying to do a treewalk yourself.

Comment: How can we extract list of files from this iterator and store it in an array? I see in this link https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/iterators.html that many functions should be available for iterator; but, cannot activate any of those except .hasNext() and .next()

Comment: This did not work for me at all. I got a lot of errors concerning s3. I don't remember what they were exactly but I tried a lot of different ways. Just commenting if someone else runs into the same thing they won't think they're crazy.

Comment: @Mahmoud `it` is an instance of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator`, not collections' iterators

Comment: This works for me. I need to define a `var` outside the while loop in order to save the results of the name of the file I am looking for. Also, in order to stop the loop once my file is found, I need to wrap the while loop inside a `breakable`, and then I can `break` once the file is found.

Comment: how to add aws access key and secret access key in to this one

Answer (score 12):

**Approach 1**

For pyspark users, I've translated Michael Spector's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065414/143447) (I'll leave it to you to decide if using this is a good idea):

```py
sc = spark.sparkContext
myPath = f's3://my-bucket/my-prefix/'
javaPath = sc._jvm.java.net.URI.create(myPath)
hadoopPath = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(myPath)
hadoopFileSystem = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(javaPath, sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
iterator = hadoopFileSystem.listFiles(hadoopPath, True)

s3_keys = []
while iterator.hasNext():
    s3_keys.append(iterator.next().getPath().toUri().getRawPath())
```

`s3_keys` now holds all file keys found at `my-bucket/my-prefix`

**Approach 2**
Here is an alternative that I found ([hat tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406156/list-all-the-files-in-azure-blob-using-databricks#comment117485101_60406156) to @forgetso):

```py
myPath = 's3://my-bucket/my-prefix/*'
hadoopPath = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(myPath)
hadoopFs = hadoopPath.getFileSystem(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
statuses = hadoopFs.globStatus(hadoopPath)

for status in statuses:
  status.getPath().toUri().getRawPath()
  # Alternatively, you can get file names only with:
  # status.getPath().getName()
```

**Approach 3 (incomplete!)**

The two approaches above do not use the Spark parallelism mechanism that would be applied on a distributed read. That logic looks private though. See `parallelListLeafFiles` [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/HadoopFSUtils.scala). I have not found a way to compel pyspark do to a distributed `ls` on s3 without also reading the file contents. I tried to use py4j to instantiate an `InMemoryFileIndex`, but can't get the incantation right. Here is what I have so far if someone wants to pick it up from here:

```
myPath = f's3://my-bucket/my-path/'
paths = sc._gateway.new_array(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, 1)
paths[0] = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(myPath)

emptyHashMap = sc._jvm.java.util.HashMap()
emptyScalaMap = sc._jvm.scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(emptyMap)

# Py4J is not happy with this:
sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex(
    spark._jsparkSession, 
    paths, 
    emptyScalaMap, 
    sc._jvm.scala.Option.empty() # Optional None
)
```

Comment: FWIW S3a in Apache Hadoop distros (not EMR) does async prefetch of the next page in the results. The whole "parallelise or not" question is an interesting one. It can be done effectively on a single host, but you have to decide between parallel shallow LIST calls vs deep sequential LISTs...really depends on the directory structure as to which is best. My current strategy is list the immediate children, then deep list under each child in separate threads.

Comment: Your incantation was very close. Bring a pentagram and a goat and see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75326116/543720

Comment: Nice find! I'm glad you spelled it out completely

Comment: I ran with the theme: https://www.perceptivebits.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-finding-files-via-spark/

Comment: It's pretty slow compared to os.scan_dir in python

Answer (score 1):

[Lou Zell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143447/lou-zell) was very close! The below ended up working on ADLS2, but I'm putting it here because of the Py4J magic. Note that the noopcache causes the job to be run twice: Once when the index is created and once when listfiles is called. I also wrote a blogpost on this: https://www.perceptivebits.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-finding-files-via-spark/

```
import os

base_path = "/mnt/my_data/"
glob_pattern = "*"
sc = spark.sparkContext
hadoop_base_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(base_path)
paths = sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq([hadoop_base_path])

#noop_cache_clazz = sc._jvm.java.lang.Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.NoopCache$")
#ff = noop_cache_clazz.getDeclaredField("MODULE$")
#noop_cache = ff.get(None)

file_status_cache_clazz = jvm.java.lang.Class.forName(
            "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileStatusCache$"
        )
ff = file_status_cache_clazz.getDeclaredField("MODULE$")
jvm_spark_session = spark._jsparkSession
file_status_cache = ff.get(None).getOrCreate(jvm_spark_session)

in_memory_file_index = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex(
    jvm_spark_session,
    paths,
    sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap({}),
    sc._jvm.scala.Option.empty(),
    file_status_catche,  # or use noop_cache if you need to save memory
    sc._jvm.scala.Option.empty(),
    sc._jvm.scala.Option.empty()
)
glob_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(os.path.join(base_path, glob_pattern))
glob_paths = sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq([glob_path])
# SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPath(fs, Path.mergePaths(validated(basep), validated(globp))),
status_list = in_memory_file_index.listLeafFiles(glob_paths)
path_list = []
iter = status_list.iterator()
while iter.hasNext():
    path_status = iter.next()
    path_list.append(str(path_status.getPath().toUri().getRawPath()))

path_list.sort()

print(path_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `input_file_name` with dataframe, it will give you absolute file-path per row.

Following code will give you all the file paths.

```
spark.read.table("zen.intent_master").select(input_file_name).distinct.collect
```

I am assuming. For your use case, you just want to read data from a set of files, with some regex, so then you can apply that in filter.

For example,

```
val df = spark.read.table("zen.intent_master").filter(input_file_name.rlike("your regex string"))
```

Comment: Oh for this particular question, it doesn't have or use a table. Is it possible to do this if there isn't a table? I just have access to the S3 folder

Comment: @codeshark you are correct but I don't have S3 setup write now, i have tested with HDFS, its working fine, i am assuming it will work with s3 too.

Comment: You can use this with s3 as well like:  
    `val blah = spark.read.json("s3://blah-bucket/blah-folder/")  
    val blahWithFilename =  blah.withColumn("filename", input_file_name)  
    blahWithFilename.show(false)`

Comment: That will load the whole data into DF.
When you need only a list of files from the S3 bucket with recursive lookup what for downloading files itself?
Data could be to heavy and processing might take days.