# List all the files in Azure Blob using databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-blob-storage

I am after a pyspark(python) script to list all the files in Azure blob storage(including subdirectories). I found a script for this purpose in scala, need help in converting this script to pyspark.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data/list-delete-files-faster#list-files
Scala code

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path, FileSystem}
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex
import java.net.URI

def listFiles(basep: String, globp: String): Seq[String] = {
  val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(basep), conf)

  def validated(path: String): Path = {
    if(path startsWith "/") new Path(path)
    else new Path("/" + path)
  }

  val fileCatalog = InMemoryFileIndex.bulkListLeafFiles(
    paths = SparkHadoopUtil.get.globPath(fs, Path.mergePaths(validated(basep), validated(globp))),
    hadoopConf = conf,
    filter = null,
    sparkSession = spark)

  fileCatalog.flatMap(_._2.map(_.path))
}

val root = "/mnt/path/table"
val globp = "[^_]*" // glob pattern, e.g. "service=webapp/date=2019-03-31/*log4j*"

val files = listFiles(root, globp)
files.toDF("path").show()
```

I have managed to convert the code to pyspark but I am getting the below error.

> 'JavaMember' object has no attribute 'globPath'

```py
configuration = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf
fspath = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs
hadooputil = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
inmemfileindex = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex
javauri = sc._jvm.java.net.URI

rootURL = "/mnt/"
globp = "[^_]*" #glob pattern, e.g. "service=webapp/date=2019-03-31/*log4j*"

conf = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jvm.java.net.URI(rootURL),conf)


g=sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.mergePaths(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(rootURL),  sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/" + globp))

hadooputil.get.globPath(fs,g)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use `globStatus` which is part of `hadoop.fs` e.g. `files = fspath.globStatus(Path('/service=webapp/date=2019-03-31/*log4j*'))` [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258750/1178971)

Comment: @forgetso I have added an answer based on your comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050173/143447, thank you!